Bridged Vertices Show an Indentation
I bridged two objects. In edit and object mode it shows a smooth, single object. Rendered view shows an indentation where the two sides were bridged. I cannot sculpt it smooth, smooth vertices in edit mode or otherwise fix this distortion. There are no doubles, overlapping or hidden vertices and the two object are joined.
The steps that I took: the object was copied/pasted (see the image where the collections tab is open, image 3) and the mirror modifier removed. I then duplicated the newly unmirrored object, transform-x'ed, aligned, and bridged the duplicated side.
I am using three modifiers: cloth, subdivision, and solidify. All physics settings are mostly defaults. I am using Blender 3.6





Check that the face orientation is the same on both sides by checking Face Orientation on the top-right Viewport Overlays menu. The whole object should be blue. If half is red, go into Edit mode, select All, and then hit Shift-N to recalculate the normals. See if that fixes the problem.

@johnEason, flipping the normals removed the indentation. Ty, Cheers!

Good! It's usually the first thing to check.

I know this but forgot. Won't forget it again.
